# javax.mail From address specified is not used for sending the mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send email from my Java code. I'm using the javax.mail library.
This is my code:

```
public class SendMail {

public void postMail(final String recipients, final String subject, final String message) throws MessagingException {
    boolean debug = false;
    java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "gmail-smtp.l.google.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

    session.setDebug(debug);
    try {

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress("me@gmail.com");
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
        InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress(recipients);
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setContent(message, "text/html");
        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("SendMail:postMail - " + e.getMessage() + "; " + e.getCause());
    }
}


private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username@gmail.com", "password");
    }
}
```

}

Everything worsk fine but when recipients recive the message, the sender is not the one I specified but the one I used for the authentication. So in this case, the sender is "username@gmail.com" instead of "me@gmail.com" that I used for the instruction message.setFrom.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: If you want to send a mail having some other sender instead of the account you are sending from, you need to use an smtp server that allows the same. Google uses authentication to prevent people from sending emails using non-existent mail ids. Hence, Even though you set the sender xyz@gmail.com, your original mail id will be used.

Comment: Ok, maybe I will change provider. Thank you @Logan

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add

```
 props.put("mail.from", "me@gmail.com");
```

Which is used not in the message but at the beginning of the SMTP Transaction.

See http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SMTPMailTransactionProcess-3.htm

and http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/